# How do I get the path to the usb flash drive or access it?

Tags: java, android, permissions, usb, android-sdcard

During the development of the application, we encountered a problem. We connect a USB flash drive to the device via OTG cable. We request access rights from the user, but in the end we get nothing.

As a result, we started looking at what the path to Total Commander looks like. It looks something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lr60s.png)

As a result, we realized that the system hides the file. Please tell me what permissions are needed so that you can access the flash drive files directly.

We tried to write simple Java code to display the contents of the folder on the screen, but we couldn't find the way to our flash drive.

```
String path = new File(Objects.requireNonNull(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getParent())).getParent();
```

Tested on several devices, we noticed that only 2 flash drives are displayed and have access to them, since they are displayed on the path /storage/emulated/0, on the rest there is no and we will change the path ///USB_.

The permission we gave:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USB_PERMISSION" />
```

!API 29!

Comment: "Please tell me what permissions are needed so that you can access the flash drive files directly" -- `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` should work, though the user would need to grant it manually in Settings, and you might not be allowed to distribute your app through the Play Store or elsewhere. Consider using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree` and let the user decide where the content is that the user wants you to use.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We are not interested in Google Play. The problem is that we would not like to implement an internal just an internal explorer in the application and immediately conditionally along the path /storage/... or /mnt/... get access to the flash drive. On some devices it works, and on some android hides the path to the flash drive.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.